# Printing in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, printing

I have a couple of lines of code. I am trying to figure out an alternative way of printing this in bash. I have tried a couple of different echo's and have mixed it up but im not quite getting the desired out come...

Here is my code: PS I am printing out a tranposed matrix of numbers, and it prints fine how it is already. Just want an alternative way.

```
for((m=0;m<NUM_OF_COLS;m++))
do 
    printf "%d" "${trans[0, $m]}"
    for((i=1;i<NUM_COUNT;i++))
    do
        printf '\t'
        printf '%s' ${trans[$i, $m]}
    done
    echo
done 
exit 0
```

Comment: Other than combining the `printf` and `print` into a single command, I don't see any way to improve it.

Comment: [codereview.se] is the site for asking for design improvements.

Comment: oops yeah I forgot to add that haha.

Comment: Do it as one line `printf '\t%s' "${trans[$i, $m}"`

Comment: Oh okay cool. Thank you!